# Could we get an opt-in feature to get notified when fellow mods record an absence?

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, notifications, moderators, email-notification

I logged into one of the sites I moderate this morning and just happened to check the dashboard and noticed that one of the mods had recorded their absence. It got me thinking--if I hadn't happened to check, I would have had no idea we were down one mod. Now, I know any mod can easily notify fellow mods in chat, but I understand how sometimes that might fall by the wayside (it certainly has for me before). The mod absence record is already completely visible to other mods, so would it be possible to have a checkbox above it to be notified of changes? I don't care whether it's a Stack Exchange inbox notification or an email or either/both.

Comment: I just tend to leave a note on our group chat. If I'm on a mod break, I'm probably non communicable or just need a break so its nice to let the other mods know

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yes, that's in my question.

Answer (score 3):

The least intrusive solution might be to put an indication on the main dashboard at `/admin/dashboard` where the outstanding flags are displayed as this is probably where most moderators go to see if there's anything that needs their immediate attention.

This doesn't require you to view any other pages or opt in to a notification to find out that a moderator has marked themselves as absent and most moderators will visit the dashboard on a regular basis.

Comment: It already does that :D

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I know it's on the history tab, but it is on the main dashboard page?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek No, it doesn't. You're probably thinking of the `/admin` page which is also referred to as the dashboard.

Comment: I think I'd be fine with this solution. I check flags all the time, so I'd be likely to see it there.